# How do I reinterpret the exponents (2^31, ..., 2^0) of an integer?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have a regular 32 bit Integer where the bits represent b31*2^31, b30*2^30, ..., b0*2^0 respectively.

Is there a way to decrease each exponent by 32, i.e. calculate b31*2^-1 + b30*2^-2 + ... + b0*2^-32 (similar to an IEEE Float mantissa) without having to extract the bits (e.g. using shifts or mod)?

E.g. for an 8 bit Integer, if input is 0010 1111 = 47 then output is **0** * 2^-1 + **0** * 2^-2 + **1** * 2^-3 + **0** * 2^-4 + **1** * 2^-5 + **1** * 2^-6 + **1** * 2^-7 + **1** * 2^-8 = 0.18359375.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. What is your desired end result? Can you give an example? If you convert the integer to a double and divide by 2^32, you'll get the right number, but I don't know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited my post to make the question more clear.

Comment: I understand the math, I just don't understand what sort of method you expect to do this. An integer will never give you a value of 0.18359375. You'll have to convert it to a floating-point value.

Comment: Or possibly fixed-point, if your language supports that.

Comment: Converting to fixed point and then shifting is a great idea, that actually solved my problem, thanks!